# Issue with validation when model has three belongsTo associations with another model

Tags: validation, cakephp, formhelper

Some validation messages are missing on my form, though they are correct in the result of `invalidMessages()`. If I enter the last name for the ATCSTudent.lastName, then I don't get a validation message for lastName on ATCGradChair1. I tried fix for 3828 but it doesn't work.

I have a model with this belongs to:

```
public $belongsTo = array(

'ATCStudent' => array('className' => 'Person', 'foreignKey' => 'studentId'),

'ATCProgram' => array('className' => 'Program', 'foreignKey' => 'programId'),

'ATCGradChair1' => array('type' => 'inner', 'className' => 'Person', 'foreignKey' => 'gradChair1Id'),

'ATCGradChair2' => array('className' => 'Person', 'foreignKey' => 'gradChair2Id'),

);
```

My view looks like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('ATCForm', array('novalidate' => true));

echo $this->Form->input('id');

//echo $this->Form->input('ATCStudent.id');

echo $this->Form->input('ATCStudent.lastName');

echo $this->Form->input('ATCStudent.firstName');

echo $this->Form->input('ATCStudent.emplId');

echo $this->Form->input('ATCStudent.campusId');

echo $this->Form->input('ATCStudent.email');

echo $this->Form->input('progCode', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$programs));

echo $this->Form->input('termCode', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$terms));

echo $this->Form->input('prelimDate');

echo "<p>Enter below only cross-listed courses and/or courses taken at another institution.

";
echo $this->Form->input('cognate');

//echo $this->Form->input('ATCGradChair1.id');

echo $this->Form->inputs(array('legend'=> 'Graduate Chair 1', 'ATCGradChair1.firstName', 'ATCGradChair1.lastName', 'ATCGradChair1.campusId'));

//echo $this->Form->input('ATCGradChair2.id');

echo $this->Form->inputs(array('legend'=> 'Graduate Chair 2', 'ATCGradChair2.firstName', 'ATCGradChair2.lastName', 'ATCGradChair2.campusId'));

echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

Most fields are required. I'm using saveAll with deep option to save and validate. It appears that the call to _introspectModel in tagIsInvalid does not return the correct array of validation messages when it's checking the fields on ATCGradChair1.

Is my view incorrect or is this a bug?

Comment: I believe you're supposed to use the main model in the $this->Form->create() ... do you have model 'ATCForm'?  If not, try changing it to your main model, and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave.  I am using 'ATCForm' in Form->create and that is my main model. The sub-model is Person, but I have three Person references in ATCForm.  However ATCStudent, ATCGradChair1 and ATCGradChair2 are not model names, but the name I give in belongsTo.